# Django bug - auto_now_add field is Null

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

My model has a custom primary key and a DateTimefield with auto_now_add = True:

```
slug = models.CharField(max_length=5, primary_key=True)
created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I noticed that a handful of objects out of several hundred have a value of Null for "created_on", even though this field does not allow Null values. Any ideas how this is possible?

This key is randomly generated via this custom save override:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.slug == '':
        self.slug = generate_random_slug()
    while True:
        try:
            super(MyClass, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            break
        except IntegrityError:
            self.slug = generate_random_slug()
```

Comment: Did you add `created_on` field in initial migration?

Comment: This field was added in a later migration, with a default value. What's strange is that only a handful of these objects out of hundreds have a Null value, it's not something we've been able to replicate.

Comment: The code you show does not preclude null values. Please post your model code, particularly any custom save, pre_save or post_save methods you might have.

Comment: Added more code. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4):

If you try to save an object that has a field with `primary_key=True` and another with `auto_now_add=True` where there is already an object in the db with the same primary key value it will cause an error to be thrown by the DB or possibly just set it null. Looks like you most likely are getting a collision in your slug (looks like it is 5 chars long which is going to create collisions pretty easily). You probably want to use a `generate_random_slug` with lower collision probability. Something like `uuid` could be useful.

This is a hypothesis and would need to see more code to confirm.